# Precentage calculation error in shopify code

Tags: shopify

I'm running shopify and recently found an error which is the calculation of current price and compare price.
I've been trying to figure out how to solve this problem for a week and I'm guessing its in the coding which I'm not very used to.

Down below is the code running in my website at product-badge.liquid file I've also posted a picture of the badges showing "SALE" and precentage cut.

Hope anyone could help me! Kind regards/pleb.

```
{% if sold_out %}
<span class="soldout-title">{{ settings.soldout_title }}</span>
{% else %}

{% if on_sale %}
{% if settings.sale_title != '' %}
<span class="sale-title">{{ settings.sale_title }}</span>
{% endif %}
{% if settings.sale_percent_enable %}
<span class="percent-count">-{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.compare_at_price | minus: product.selected_or_first_available_variant.price | times: 100.0 | divided_by: product.selected_or_first_available_variant.compare_at_price | money_without_currency | replace: ',', '.' | times: 100 | remove: '.0'}}%</span>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnYPV.png)

Comment: That's not HTML

Comment: The code that is doing the calculation isn't HTML.

Comment: Why are you converting the result to text (using the `money_without_currency` filter) and then performing text manipulation on the `,`/`.` separator before doing more math? Does it work better if you get rid of the text manipulation filters and just use the `round` filter to get the desired number of decimal points? (https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/math-filters#round)

Answer (score 3):

I've tried your code on my test store and **it works**, of course, the only part I tested is the one you mentioned that is meant to display the discount percentage so the following:

```html
<span class="percent-count">-{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.compare_at_price | minus: product.selected_or_first_available_variant.price | times: 100.0 | divided_by: product.selected_or_first_available_variant.compare_at_price | money_without_currency | replace: ',', '.' | times: 100 | remove: '.0'}}%</span>
```

First off, let's take advantage of [liquid variables](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/tags/variable-tags) to make this readable and the result is the following:

```html
{% assign price = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.price %}
{% assign compare_at_price = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.compare_at_price %}
{% assign discount_percentage = compare_at_price
    | minus: price
    | times: 100.0
    | divided_by: compare_at_price
    %}
<span class="percent-count">-{{ discount_percentage | round: 0 }}%</span>
```

I got rid of some filters since:

1. The `money_without_currency` filter is not needed (the discount percentage is a ratio, not a currency)
2. The subsequent formatting like using comma rather than dot should be done at output time but in this case, it's just better to use the `round` filter as suggested by [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592369/dave-b) (I've set the round at 0 explicitly but if you want no decimal part just omit the parameter or change it if you want the decimals)

**What is causing the error**

This code works as long as you have the values of `price` and `compare_at_price` so if it still doesn't work just check the value of these variables with the following code (remove it after checking with the javascript console, it's just for debugging purposes):

```html
<script>
    console.log({{ product | JSON }});
    console.log("Price: "+ {{ price }});
    console.log("Compate_at_price: "+ {{ compare_at_price }});
</script>
```

Make sure to paste it **after** the snippet I previously inserted, then check with `F12` on Chrome.